# Strange behavior when streaming sink to Parquet file

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.12.0, and I have following full code that demonstrate how to write streaming events to Parquet files.

When I run the code, I observed two things:

1. `println(s"$i is emitted")` in the StudentSource#run always prints `0 is emitted`, and no `1 is emitted` is printed or other value for the `i`
2. When I look at the ouput directory, I saw may`new empty` files (with `inprogress` in the filename)  are created every second.

I have enabled the checkpoint. How can I find where the problem is?

```
package org.example.official.connector

import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path
import org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.avro.ParquetAvroWriters
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.CheckpointingMode
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite

import scala.beans.BeanProperty

case class Student(
                    @BeanProperty id: Int,
                    @BeanProperty name: String
                  )

class StudentSource(val emitInterval: Int = 0) extends SourceFunction[Student] {
  override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[Student]): Unit = {
    (0 to 100).foreach {
      i =>
        ctx.collect(Student(i, s"name-$i"))
        //always print 0 is emitted
        println(s"$i is emitted")
        if (emitInterval > 0) {
          Thread.sleep(emitInterval)
        }
    }

    //Keep the source running
    while (true) {
      Thread.sleep(100)
    }

  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = {
  }
}

class StreamParquetAvroFileSink_001 extends AnyFunSuite {
  def enableCheckpoint(env: StreamExecutionEnvironment) = {
    env.enableCheckpointing(5 * 1000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointInterval(5 * 1000)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION)
    val path = "file:///D:/flink-checkpoints/"

    println(s"checkpoint path is ${path}")
    val backend = new FsStateBackend(path)
    env.setStateBackend(backend)
  }

  //The test suite
  test("StreamParquetAvroFileSink_001") {
    val path = new Path("file:///D:/data01/logs/aa")
    val sink: StreamingFileSink[Student] = StreamingFileSink
      .forBulkFormat(path, ParquetAvroWriters.forReflectRecord(classOf[Student]))
      .build()
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(3)
    enableCheckpoint(env)
    val ds = env.addSource(new StudentSource(emitInterval = 1000))
    ds.addSink(sink)
    env.execute()

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem with the code? Do you have an error? Or are you wondering why there are multiple files open every second? It is strange also where you placed the `while (true) {` with only a sleep inside. Why? There should be a code that always generate events for the source....

Comment: thanks @Felipe. The problem is that there is no `finished` files in the output directory,they are always in `inprogress` state. With `while(true)`, I am just writing the demo code and   want to keep my source operator running.